# Multiple IF functions in Excel: how to override on IF statement if another IF is true.

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have two columns of data.

```
1 FALSE
2 FALSE
3 FALSE
4 FALSE
5 TRUE
6 TRUE
7 TRUE
8 TRUE

44.0099
16.043
30.0696
44.0972
58.1234
58.1234
72.1503
65.5401
```

I want to write an IF statement with multiple nested IFs such that:

```
IF(8=TRUE,72.1503, IF(8 & 7 = True, 65.4501,.... IF( 8:1 = True, 44.0099)
```

However, when more cells are 'True', I want this to override the preceding IF statement.

For example, say if 8 and 7 are True, I want the result of this to override the result if just 8 is True and so on.... if 8 and 7 and 6 are True, I want this to override the result of that if just 8 and 7 are True.

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Are you saying that what you want to return is the number in the second range whose position corresponds to the position of the first TRUE element in the first range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `AND(logical1, [logical2], ...)` function of Excel in your IF statements to concatenate more conditions. (read more about AND here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9)

Also you need to turn the logic around. You need to check if all fields are `TRUE` first. Then if field 2-8 are `TRUE` and so on...

So your statement would look something like this:

```
IF(AND(A8=TRUE,A7=TURE, A6=TRUE, ...), 1,
    IF(AND(A8=TRUE,A7=TURE, ...), 2,
        IF(AND(A8=TRUE, ...), 3,)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=IF(AND(A3:A5)=TRUE,3,IF(AND(A3:A4)=TRUE,2,IF(A3=TRUE,1)))
```

or, even simpler:

```
=IF(AND(A3:A5),3,IF(AND(A3:A4),2,IF(A3,1)))
```

assuming that your data is in cells A3:A5 like:

Output:

```
A3:A5:     result
TRUE 
TRUE
TRUE  -->  3

A3:A5:     result
TRUE 
TRUE
FALSE -->  2

A3:A5:     result
TRUE 
FALSE
FALSE -->  1
```

The  `if` statement starts with the "higher priority" conditions and slowly works its way down to the mode basic ones.